# what is a word for seeing inside someone

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a word to describe the layers of a personality or person.  I am trying to describe how one could actually see into another person.

Comment: An X-ray machine?

Comment: Further clarification would help.

Comment: Psychologist sometimes refer to aspects of personality with the word trait, coming from trait theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_theory).

Comment: It's pretty dark and icky inside people.  That's why doctors charge a lot

Comment: Ermm... per Tim's comment, I think you mean ***figuratively***, not *actually*.

Comment: Do you mean how "someone can *read* a person's inner thoughts"? Or how they are able to understand how a person 'ticks'?

Comment: If you edit your question to resolve the ambiguity about the word "actually," I'll vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to describe how one could **actually** see into another person.

The problem is you used the word *actually*: as an actual fact; really. In other words, you have used a non-figurative word for looking into one. Unless you are using sophisticated implements to do so, such as MRI's or endoscopes, you can't.

If you want to describe a **metaphorical incisiveness** on your part, you can describe *peeling away layers of defense or superficiality* to get at the more vulnerable person beneath.

If you mean something else, you will need to provide clarification in your question by editing it.

Comment: Literally? Or literally literally?

Comment: +1 for interpreting the question correctly. (By "correctly", I mean as I have interpreted the question :P)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention 'personality' in the OP, I am assuming that you are not talking about a physical look at the interior of the body. That would be relatively easy to answer with suggestions like X-rays, ultrasound, MRI scans, and physically cutting them open.

But if you are talking about their psyche, there are essentially two different areas of science involved, one is psychology and the other neuroscience.

The former is the study of the mind, and the only known method of understanding that is by use of psychoanalysis. The problem with psychoanalysis is that it can be difficult to get different psychiatrists to agree on the interpretation of results.

Neuroscience is the study of the physical brain, and that uses methods not dissimilar to those for examining the rest of the body. Whilst it can explain things like problems of bodily co-ordination, memory loss etc, it cannot determine much about 'personality'.

Only clinical psychologists, and psychiatrists attempt to describe personality scientifically, after exhaustive work with the patient.